# Is there an alternative DLNA player for Logitech Revue under Google-TV?

Tags: media-player, dlna, google-tv, logitech-revue

The Logitech Media Player included with the Logitech review is problematic - occasionally pausing causes it to stop or jump from video playback to music, etc. I am not seeing any alternative DLNA players in the Android Market that run under Google-TV. Are there any others out there that I am missing? Running Honeycomb 3.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aVia Media Player is compatible with Google TV and is available in the Android Market on Google TV.
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.videon.android.mediaplayer

Answer (score 1):

I use Plex, and have had good results with it (also available in the Android Market)  Plex seems to play a lot more of my video files than the stock Logitech app.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.plexapp.gtv